# Java: Javascript function does not trigger on Wicket button's onclick event

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I have a Javascript function that triggers on a button's "onclick" event.

```
<input type="button" value="Verify" id="b1" onclick=myFunction() />
```

I need to disable this button on another button's `onSubmit()` method in Wicket. For that I figure I'll use `setEnabled(false)`. But if I bind the button with Wicket, its `onclick` event in HTML does not trigger.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" wicket:id="verify" value="Verify" id="b1" onclick=myFunction() />
```

Java:

```
public class MyPanel  extends Panel {
    public MyPanel(...){
        // other components

        Button verify = (Button) new Button("verify");
        verifyThumb.setEnabled(true);

        // other components
    }
}
```

I need to call the Javascript function as well as disable the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
<input type="button" wicket:id="verify" value="Verify" id="b1" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

You have to put quotes around the onclick function

Answer (score 1):

Please verify your input tag. You have missed "" for onclick event.

```
<input type="button" wicket:id="verify" value="Verify" id="b1" onclick="myFunction()" />
```